# Can ffprobe return the mime type?

Tags: ffmpeg, mime-types, ffprobe

I want to get the mime type (e.g. video/mp4) of a media file using ffprobe. Is that possible or do I need another program for that?

Comment: *"Can ffprobe return the mime type?"* No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just found out, while working on another project, if you do `ffmpeg -h muxer=mp4`, it also shows the mime type. This has made it a lot easier for me. I can run `ffprobe testvid.mp4`, find the file type and then use the `-h muxer=` method to get the mime type.

Answer (score 6):

The [`file`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command may be able to get you what you want. It even has a `--mime-type` flag you can set to pull that data out specifically.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need my program to work on Windows, but I've found a Java library called ```simplemagic``` which does what I need. I'll leave both solutions here, since one only works on linux and one only works with Java.

Comment: Then your question would rather be “How to get the mime type of a video on Windows?”

Comment: One small caveat: it might recognize .mp4 files with only audio streams as "video/mp4" instead of "audio/mp4". Otherwise, the file command works really well. If you use Python, you could also use python-magic or the built-in mimetypes package.

Comment: The applicability of this answer depends on a target platform. Not all versions of the `file` command support this feature.